# how can i edit web content made from typo3

Tags: typo3, content-management-system

I have created a new account on typo3. My need is to edit my personal details on my company webpage. Should i also install typo3 cms on my machine to be able to do this? I never used any cms platforms before. Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 is a CMS where all scripts are located on the server. As an editor you interact with web forms. This means: aside a web browser you need no further software on your computer.

Be aware that an account on typo3.org has nothing to do with the TYPO3 installation of your company.
If you want access to the TYPO3 installation of your company to edit your data, the adminstrator of the company website has to create an user in TYPO3 or another system where the login is connected. That could be a LDAP of your company also used for logins in other areas.

Nevertheless you could install your own TYPO3 to have a playground to get familiar with TYPO3 in general. But that would be to much hassle if you only want edit some content.

Comment: Thanks for your quick intro on this system. Its useful.